# Javascript check for multiple values if it is undefined, then return empty string for only the undefined

Tags: javascript, undefined

So I have all these consts, coming from an array that i am looping through:

```
var characters = //list of charachters and stuff
const name = character[0]
const superpower = character[1]
const haircolor = character[2]
```

I am then rendering everything in a table that works perfectly, except, if a value is missing it returns undefined.

So my question is; how can I check for every value if it is undefined? And if it undefined, how can I display for that value a empty string.

For example:
Current situation

```
...
Mario, mushroom, black
Luigi, fire flower, black
Peach, undefined, blond
Toad, undefined, undefined
...
```

What I want to do:

```
Mario Mushroom Black
Luigi Fire flower, Black
Peach Blond
Toad
```

the answer is probably really easy but i cant quite figure it out xd
...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(value || '')
```

will log an empty string if value is undefined

Comment: Oh wow that is pretty cool, Thanks for the help!!!!